# How to sorting an array of Objects using comparator in python

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to translate a cpp code to python. How to do it?

`sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), subjectCompare);`

Given

```
{
    string name, start, finish;
};

bool subjectCompare(Subject s1, Subject s2)
{
    return (s1.finish < s2.finish);
}
```

arr is array of Subject

`sorted()` with `key= operator.attrgetter()` can be used for sorting array of objects according to a attribute. Is there anyway to sort array of objects using a comparator.

Answer (score 0):

"When implementing ordering operations with rich comparisons, it is best to implement all six operations (`__eq__, __ne__, __lt__, __le__, __gt__, __ge__`) rather than relying on other code to only exercise a particular comparison.

To minimize the effort involved, the `functools.total_ordering()` decorator provides a tool to generate missing comparison methods." - PEP8

One approach could be:

```py
from functools import total_ordering 


@total_ordering
class Subject():
    
    def __init__(self, name, start, finish):
         self.n = name
         self.s = start
         self.f = finish


    def __repr__(self):
        """ returns a string containing a printable
            representation of a Subject object"""
        # e.g: start.finish concatenation
        # return str("{}.{}".format(self.s,self.f))
        return str(self.f)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """ implement comparison between Subject objects """
        return self.f.strip == other.f.strip()
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        """ implement comparison between Person objects """
        return self.f.strip < other.f.strip()

    ## good to implement all __le__(), __gt__(),  __ge__(), __eq__()
   



if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = Subject("alex","startvalue","finishvalue")
    b = Subject("opri","startvalue","longerfiishvalue")

    subject_list = []
    subject_list.append(a)
    subject_list.append(b)

    
    # __eq__ usage
    print(a==b)

    # __lt__ usage
    print(a<b)

    # sorted list descending
    sorted_subject_list = sorted(subject_list )

    # sorted list ascending
    sorted_subject_list_2 = sorted(subject_list , key= lambda subject : subject.f)
```

Basically you can choose/implement the criteria on which `Subject` objects are compared and therefore sorted.

Answer (score -1):

You could define the magic method "__lt__"

```py
class Subject:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.finish < other.finish
```

Comment: How to add this in sorted function

Comment: You dont need to add anything. Call sorted without the "key" parameter, i.e., sorted(arr)